# Generate email using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I have done a full day of research on this issue and I've come up with nothing. There are many scripts out there to create a client-side email using JS. In my case, I have successfully been able to append a phone number to a number of domain extensions.

This is an example result of this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/N3kJb/)**...

```
4808565309@message.Alltel.com;
 4808565309@txt.att.net;
 4808565309@myboostmobile.com;
 4808565309@sms.mycricket.com;
 4808565309@mymetropcs.com;
 4808565309@messaging.sprintpcs.com;
 4808565309@page.nextel.com;
 4808565309@vtext.com;
 4808565309@tmomail.net;
 4808565309@email.uscc.net;
 4808565309@vmobl.com
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is use an onClick reference to carry these emails into a client-side email client (Outlook in my case).

This is similar to a **mailto:**, but appending the entire textarea class to the **mailto:** is my goal.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why store the domain names in the `<input>` tags? Just keep them in an array in js.

Comment: To send, you'll need to just loop through them and for each one do: `window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');`

Comment: do you want to open the client mail with text set?

Comment: @JonathanM Wouldn't that generate a separate email for each one?

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what you wanted. Are you wanting all of the email addresses in the "To:" section and send one email to all?

Comment: Yes, sir. You nailed it. I just can't get the textarea class to append to the "mailto:"... I can do it for the body of the email (not my goal), but not the "To:". Does that make sense?

Comment: You also might be interested in the [Mandrill API](http://mandrillapp.com).

Comment: @webfrogs You need to concatenate all email addresses with a comma between them. Something like `emails.join(',');` and then use that in `mailto:`.

Comment: Also, since you are generating the emails, I don't think you need to store them in a textarea and then retrieve it again. Remember the emails in an array, and use that instead.

Comment: I'm creating an array for them now. That's a much more prudent way of doing things. Thanks for this!

Comment: @webfrogs, if you're going for a good, solid, cross-platform solution, you're going to need to do something else. This approach is not reliable.

Comment: @webfrogs Here's an updated fiddle. I don't have a mail client to test with, so let me know if it works: http://jsfiddle.net/N3kJb/11/

Comment: @JonathanM - You're right. It only works in Chrome, but this is a start. Any suggestions for Cross-Platform? I have to be able to do this without any server language. Has to be client-side.

Comment: @webfrogs, actually, it doesn't work in chrome if the user is using gmail. Have you considered capturing the addresses and submitting to the server to let it generate the email?

Comment: @webfrogs There's no reliable way to do it cross-platform, and in all cases. Some clients just won't allow multiple addresses, etc. The only reliable way is to use server-side code.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the push. Looks like it was the array that generated the cross-platform reliability. Thumbs up to both of you!

Comment: FYI - it's working across all platforms now.

Comment: @webfrogs, please post a fiddle. I'm doubtful that it works across all. :)

Comment: @JonathanM - I have considered the server-side code, but in the environment I'm in, PHP would be the easiest and our IT department (University as a whole) is a .net house... we run Windows servers and they refuse to install a PHP client. It sucks, but it's my reality.

Comment: @bvukelic posted the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/N3kJb/11/. Works on IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: @webfrogs, how sure do you need to be that the emails were sent? Doing stuff through the client is pretty risky. All kinds of junk can happen, including user-initiated stuff.

Comment: I never wanted the script to send any emails... I just wanted it to generate the Outlook based email (our internal client) and then the user can complete and send the email.

Comment: @webfrogs, I tried bvukelic's fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/N3kJb/11/ and it does NOT work with Chrome + gmail. There are quite a few folks using that combination.

Comment: I'm sorry... when I said all platforms, I meant browsers. I have to work on the gmail thing next. But, it solves my Outlook problem right now. I'm favoriting the fiddle and the SO link so I can come back to it.

Comment: @webfrogs FWIW, I'm using Chrome with Gmail and it almost never works with any `mailto:` link. I was too lazy to look into it, but defaults just don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correcting, you are trying to prompt an e-mail message to the users default e-mail client with a pre-populated "to" field with multiple e-mails.

```
<a href="mailto:email_address">E-mail</a>
```

If you are trying to prompt the e-mail on the button click, you can attempt to use the mailto window.location.href. However, it is very possible that it would be rejected by some browsers.

Your best bet, is to remove the submit button and changed it to a standard A tag link (you can style it like a button). Upon change of the text field, update the mailto link HREF based on the text field:

http://jsfiddle.net/N3kJb/10/

Comment: That's what I was trying to do. And I swear I tried what you did and it didn't work. It looks like I missed a set of quotes around the href. Thanks Jason!

Comment: @webfrogs, be careful. It doesn't work on my Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m using gmail.

Comment: You are definitely at the mercy of the e-mail client...and what they allow as far as multiple, pre-populated e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to do multiple recipients, there's no guaranteed safe way to do that. See this post: http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/multrec.html

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle (when click to setVal I have set a new function that open your mailclient)

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/7QUmU/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#setVal').on('click', function () {
        // Get the phone number.
        var input = $('.input').val();
        var vals = $('.combine').map(function () {
            var value = $.trim(this.value)
            // Append the phone number before the value.
            return value ? input + value : undefined;
        }).get();
        //Add the phone number to the beginning of the array
        vals.unshift();
        $('#outputAddress').val(vals.join(';\n '))
    });

    $('#setVal').on('click', function () {
        window.open('mailto:'+ $("#input2").val() + '?subject=test&body='+ $("#outputAddress").val()+ '');     
    });

});
```

Comment: I want the email addresses to display in the To: section of the email... not the body.

Comment: The addresses are in the body. They should be in the recipient.

Comment: window.open('mailto:'+ $("#outputAddress").val() + '?subject=test&body='+ 'body content test');